# Обновление приложения написанного с использованием iBeacon

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Заинтересовался модной штукой под названием iBeacon.

Возник вопрос:

Например, при заходе в магазин, хочу чтобы пользователю отправлялось уведомление: "Привет клиент!". Клиент заходит в магазин, получает уникальный идентификатор датчика и приложение выводит локальное уведомление текст которого заранее записан в приложении.

Но что делать, если я захочу изменить текст уведомления на "Привет клиент! У нас сегодня скидка". Придется выпускать обновление приложения с новым текстом? Ведь я не смогу в фоновом режиме запустить метод который запросит с сервера новый текст приветствия. Или все-таки смогу?

Comment: Думали о схеме сервер и push-уведомление?

Comment: вы имеете в виду, получить данные с датчика, отправить запрос на сервер и получить пуш? думал, но такое возможно только когда приложение запущено же. Из фонового режима я не смогу отправить запрос на сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Делали такое. Мы хранили базу уведомлений локально и периодически синхронизировали её.

То есть на сервере есть все биконы и текст уведомлений для каждого и для их цепочек, это все дело загружается в апп, когда он активен. Потом в фоне при виде бикона текст локально подгружается.